# Probability distribution for paths of fixed length in a discrete time Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a discrete-time Markov chain $M$, we assign the probability of a certain path $p$ to be
$$\mathrm{Pr}(p)=\prod x_i$$
where the product is over each edge weight in the path (with multiplicity for loops).

Let $A_n$ be the set of all paths of length $n$ in the underlying graph. Is there a tool/theorem/reference for how to determine a probability distribution for the probabilities of the paths in $A_n$?

Comment: The probability that $M$ takes a path $p$ is exactly $Pr(p)$ as you have defined it, so the distribution $D$ is just $D(p) := Pr(p)$ for all $p$ of length $n$. Are you really interested in the distribution on paths, or do you actually want the distribution of $M$ after $n$ steps?

Comment: I am interested in the distribution on paths for my application. I was hoping there was a theorem in this vain. Even just knowing that the distribution should be normal/uniform would be useful knowledge for me.